# Odoo Nginx force users to use subdomain URL

Tags: nginx, subdomain, odoo

I am using Odoo 10. I have implemented subdomain using Nginx with below script and it is working fine. However When I type IP address with port number like http://444.444.444.44:8085/web/database/manager,  still im able to access this page. I want users forcibly use subdomain only as I provided xxx.mydomain.com. How can I achieve this plz help.

My script for each of my subdoain URL is as follows:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  xxx.mydomain.org;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8085;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout       2000;
        proxy_send_timeout          2000;
        proxy_read_timeout          2000;
        send_timeout                2000;
    }


    location ~* /web/database/manager {

        deny all;
    }

    location ~* /web/database/selector {

        deny all;
    }


        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need a firewall in front of the server to block access on any port that is not 80.

Comment: And for the sake of security use https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of of listening on every interface for Odoo process, use only localhost `127.0.0.1` interface to listen. To achieve that, modify the Odoo configuration file `*.conf` and add the following:

```
xmlrpc_interface = 127.0.0.1
```

Save the `conf` file and restart Odoo process. By default Odoo process listens to all interface, but this particular line in configuration file will ensure that Odoo process listens to `127.0.0.1` only, so anyone trying to browse from `http://444.444.444.44:8085` will not find any response.